# Showing a bijection without a specific function (and only with cardinality)

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, define $I_n = \{k \in \mathbb{N} \mid k \leq n\}$. And for any set $A$, the number of elements in $A$ is $n$ if there exists a bijection from $I_n$ to $A$.
>
> Say the number of elements in $A$ is $n$, and the number of elements in $B$ is $m$. $A \cap B = \varnothing$. Prove the number of elements in $A \cup B$ is $n + m$.
>
> (Full credit requires a production of a bijection and proof that it is a bijection.)

We are given that there are bijections from $I_n$ to $A$ and $I_m$ to $B$.

So for example, there is a bijection from $I_2 = \{1, 2\}$ to $A = \{3, 4\}$, and there is a bijection from $I_3 = \{1, 2, 3\}$ to $B = \{5, 6, 7\}$. However, $A \cup B = \{3, 4, 5, 6, 7\}$ and $I_{2+3} = \{1, 2, 3\}$ so there cannot exist a bijection from $I_{n+m}$ to $A \cup B$.

I am confused because there's no restriction on $I_n$ and $I_m$ having overlapping elements, and I assumed because they both came from $\mathbb{N}$, $1 \in I_n = 1' \in I_m$ so you can't say $1$ and $1'$ are two different elements in the set $I_{n+m}$.

So while it's certainly true that the number of elements in $A \cup B$ is $n + m$ (in my specific example, it's $5$ elements), it doesn't imply that there is a bijection from $I_{n+m}$ to $A \cup B$. So how can I do this proof?

Comment: $I_{m+n} \neq I_m \cup I_n$ (unless $m = 0$ or $n = 0$). $I_{2+3} = I_5 = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$. You need a bijection $I_n \to \{m+1,m+2,\dotsc,m+n\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the number of elements in A is n, you have a bijection, between the elements of A and the numbers 1 through n.   Lets call that bijection $f:I_n\to A$,  and for ease of notation,  let's call the range elements of $f$ $f(1)=a_1,f(2)=a_2$,etc., so $f(i)=a_i$.

Similarly, you have a bijection $g:I_m\to B$,   so $g(k)=b_k$.

So, we just need a bijection $h:I_{m+n}\to A\cup B$.   The natural thing is to use f and g.   So, define h piecewise:   for $k\in I_{m+n}$,   if $1\le k\le n$,  define $h(k)=a_k$.   If $n+1\le k\le n+m$,  define $h(k)=b_{k-n}$.

Now you just have to show this is a bijection, which is pretty trivial:  If you have two different elements of $I_{n+m}$ , they either get mapped to different elements of A (Since f is a bijection, different elements of B (likewise), or an element of A and an element of B (And since A and B are disjoint, they are not equal)  Thus,  you have injective.

For surjective,  any element of $a_k\in A$ is $h(f^{-1}(k))$, and any element $b_k\in B$ is $h(g^{-1}(k-n))$,  so all elements are hit.